# JMETER jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to know how to run jmeter - webdriver sampler by using chrome browser. Is there any new plugins need to be downloaded for chrome? And this is my sample script to open in chrome browser,

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

And I have configured **jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config** config element in my test plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use Chrome browser you need to download [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) binary and drop it somewhere to your local disk.

Once done you need to specify the full path to the ChromeDriver executable under [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) like:

[image: JMeter Path to ChromeDriver]

This way you should be able to integrate WebDriver and Chrome with JMeter.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) for the most commonly asked questions regarding the WebDriver sampler solutions.